# Inserting data into a sql database from python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a table in python that i want to convert to .db format.
However, when i run my code in the IDLE, the table is created with headlines, but the data isn't inserted. This is my code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

c = conn.cursor()

kampData = [ 
(1,12,'','','Everton','Liverpool',2.9,3.3,2.63,0,0),
(2,12,'','','Fulham','Swansea City',3.4,3.4,2.3,0,0),
(3,12,'','','Hull City','Crystal Palace',1.91,3.5,4.75,0,0)
]

def tableCreate():    
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE TABLE(ID INT, Round INT, Date TEXT, Time TEXT, Home TEXT, Away TEXT, O1 REAL, OX REAL, O2 REAL, ScoreHome INT, ScoreAway INT)")

def insertData():
    i = 0
    while i < len(kampData):
        c.execute("INSERT INTO TEST1 (ID, Round, Date, Time, Home, Away, O1, OX, O2, ScoreHome, ScoreAway) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
              (kampData[i][0],kampData[i][1],kampData[i][2],kampData[i][3],kampData[i][4],kampData[i][5],kampData[i][6],kampData[i][7],kampData[i][8],kampData[i][9],kampData[i][10],))
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: You are not *calling* either function here either. Is this *all* your code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't call `insertData()`, and the function is overly verbose. Last but not least, you don't appear to commit the transaction.

Use `c.executemany()` to insert your whole structure in one go; no need to index each column:

```
def insertData():
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO TEST1 (ID, Round, Date, Time, Home, Away, O1, OX, O2, ScoreHome, ScoreAway) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
              kampData)
```

You would also need to *commit* your transaction:

```
conn.commit()
```

Comment: I bet `commit()` is the key here.